# Wamp does not recognize projects

Tags: wamp

I need help on how to setup Wamp. I installed it for a school project but when I wanted to access the project folder it sent me this error: "Server not found".

Find that you have to modify the index.php file is this line: $ suppress_localhost = true; Changing it to false. But now send this error: "The requested URL / other / was not found on this server". Is it necessary to configure something else?

I installed Wamp 3.0.0. Can somebody help me?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: $ suppress_localhost = false;...... after you restart the serve ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to wamp folder (wamp/ or wamp64/)
2. Open wampmanager.conf
3. Find urlAddLocalhost param and set it on: urlAddLocalhost = "on"
   There should not be the need to tweak the index.php in www folder.